# Set value from CI presenter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, mvp

I am making forms with the [ci-presenter library](https://github.com/druu/ci-presenter)  and I would like to use set_value() function. How can I use it from the presenter.

I need to set value on an input and on a textarea field.

Could I possibly put something on the view considering that all the form information is on the presenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the set_value() function as a parameter to the presenter call.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to set value like this in the form text fields.

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"
```

Comment: I know that but I can use that in the view not in a return statement.